# Magento Error to install new modules on downloader

Tags: magento, ssh, centos

I installed magento on CentOS via ssh the site works fine but when i try to            install a new module in magento downloader the follwing error appears

```
CONNECT ERROR: Failed to create directory:
/var/www/./app/code/community/VS/Ajaxscroll/Block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont try to install the modules on your web server , do it in ssh

./mage mage-setup .
./mage config-set preferred_state stable
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/REPO PACKAGE_NAME

To install the Varnish PageCache extension, you would do this:

./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Varnish_Cache

rm -rf downloader/.cache/